# update LUIS list entity

Tags: json, machine-learning, azure-language-understanding

Is it possible to update the LUIS list entity after creation? 
For example initially, I created a list entity using a json file with ['cat', 'dog']. Later, I want to update my list entity using  a json file with ['cat', 'chicken', 'duck']. Right now I am getting an error since 'cat' is already in included in my initial list entity. Of cause, I can remove the "old" list entity and create a new one with the same way, but does LUIS have functionality for updating of the list entities?

Comment: That's not valid list entity JSON. What does your actual JSON look like? I ask because it's unclear whether "cat" and "dog" are canonical forms or if they're synonyms.

Comment: I put ['cat', 'chicken', 'duck'] just like an example to describe the problem. Of cause, my json file has required formatting: [
        {
            "canonicalForm": "cat",
            "list": [
                "citty",
                "one more syn",
                "another syn"
            ]
        },
        {
            "canonicalForm": "dog",
            "list": [
                "syn 1",
                "syn 2"
            ]
        }
    ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can update a list entity with new values as long as you make sure the JSON doesn't contain existing values. So instead of

```
[
    {
        "canonicalForm": "cat"
    },
    {
        "canonicalForm": "chicken"
    },
    {
        "canonicalForm": "duck"
    }
]
```

you can just use

```
[
    {
        "canonicalForm": "chicken"
    },
    {
        "canonicalForm": "duck"
    }
]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, Kyle! it woks. I see: the key point here that new  and old json files should have no overlapping. I my case I solved it in a different way: I delete the old model and create a new one with the same name since to avoid overlapping, I need to keep the old json file at some place.